# which scenarios are suitable for SPA

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I have learnt a lot about facilities of SPA(single page application) over page relode.

But am unable to understand which type of projects rather scenarios is suitable for SPA. In which specific case we should definitely use SPA

Comment: I think this is a good question, but maybe ux.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for it?

Comment: @Subhadeep could you please mark my question as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well one suitable scenario would be the following. You have some kind of  business going on. You need a mobile and a web app. So it would be suitable for the web app to be a SPA. Because you will have to fetch data from the same data source for both your web and mobile app. So you can create a backend API (returns jsons not rendered views) which you can access from both your applications, rather than have a web app that returns views, not jsons. Anyways SPA isn't necessary in that case but it would be a good fit. Hope this helps.